# Creating a blinking dot animation with manim

Tags: manim

I would like to create an animation with `manim`, where I have a dot that turns on (instantly become visible) for `t_on` seconds, and then turns off (instantly become invisible) for `t_off` seconds. And this procedure repeats for a given total duration, e.g., `t_total`.

I have written the following code, but it just creates a black animation with no content. Note the values in the below example are `t_on=1.5`, `t_off=0.5`, and `t_total=6`.

```
from manim import *

class RecursiveDot(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        dot = Dot(color=BLUE, radius=0.2)

        animation = self.create_animation(dot, 6, 1.5, 0.5)

        self.play(animation)

    def create_animation(self, dot, total_duration, visible_duration, invisible_duration):
        num_cycles = int(total_duration // (visible_duration + invisible_duration))
        
        visible_animation = Create(dot, run_time=0)
        invisible_animation = Uncreate(dot, run_time=0)

        animations = []

        for _ in range(num_cycles):
            animations.append(visible_animation)
            animations.append(Wait(invisible_duration))
            animations.append(invisible_animation)
            animations.append(Wait(visible_duration))

        return AnimationGroup(*animations, run_time=total_duration)
```

And I generate the vide using `manim -p -ql dpath_to_where_I_saved_the_module.py RecursiveDot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the use of `Create()` and `Uncreate()` is not a good choice, because `Create` is considered by manim an animation of type "introducer", and `Uncreate()` of type "remover". The first one will be run only once (even if it appears several times in the AnimationGroup) and the second removes the object from the scene once it ends (the first time).

I would use instead `dot.animate.set_opacity()` to change the opacity of the dot between 1 and 0. Since these `.animate` based transformations are not proper animations, it is neccessary to call `.build()` after them (`.play()` does that for you, but if it is part of an AnimationGroup you have to do that manually).

Also, instead of `AnimationGroup()` I would use `Succession()`, that waits until one animation in the list is completed before starting the following one.

Finally, I think you had reversed your `Wait()`.

So my proposed code is:

```py
class Test(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        dot = Dot(color=BLUE, radius=0.2)          
        animation = self.create_animation(dot, 6, 1.5, 0.5)
        self.play(animation)

    def create_animation(self, dot, total_duration, visible_duration, invisible_duration):
        num_cycles = int(total_duration // (visible_duration + invisible_duration))
        animations = []
        for _ in range(num_cycles):
            animations.append(dot.animate(run_time=0).set_opacity(1).build())
            animations.append(Wait(visible_duration))
            animations.append(dot.animate(run_time=0).set_opacity(0).build())
            animations.append(Wait(invisible_duration))
        return Succession(*animations, run_time=total_duration)
```

Which results in:

[image: Result]

**Update**

For debugging purposes, the pass of time can be made visible with the following addition to the scene (before the main animation is called)

```py
        time = 0
        t = always_redraw(lambda :
                Text(f"Time: {time:.1f}", font_size=24).to_corner(UL)
        )
        def time_tracker(dt):
            nonlocal time
            time += dt
        self.add_updater(time_tracker)
        self.add(t)
```

This produces

[image: Result with time]

Comment: What if I want to rotate the dot at the same time? Like rotating it around a circle.